# Start a "throwaway" MySQL session for testing code?

Tags: python, mysql, unit-testing, ubuntu

If I want to be able to test my application against a empty MySQL database each time my application's testsuite is run, how can I start up a server as a non-root user which refers to a empty (not saved anywhere, or in saved to `/tmp`) MySQL database?

My application is in Python, and I'm using `unittest` on Ubuntu 9.10.

Comment: Any reason you don't just have `DROP DATABASE foo; CREATE DATABASE foo;` run against a running MySQL server for the tests?

Comment: I'm looking for a way (read: command-to-run) to start up a server on a system that has MySQL installed, but not necessarily running. My user may also not have the rights to start the server "normally".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--datadir for just the data or --basedir

Comment: the full command I ended up wanting to run was:
mysqld --no-defaults --datadir $SOME_TEMP_DIR --socket mysql.socket --skip-grant

Comment: You might also want to add --skip-networking or make sure you set the --port to something else than 3306. Just to make sure.
Putting these in option file is also good: mysqld --defaults-file=my_testsuite.cnf (it will ignore the other option files)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Blackhole and Memory table types in MySQL.

Comment: IMHO, if you are testing your application, it's better to use the storage engine which it will use later.

Comment: @geertjanvdk: Sure, I just posted my question since I didn't knew any other option... We are always learning! =)